# Can't get all the values from json (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get different values from a json data.

Altought I can get the description value from it, I can't get its name value.

Here is my app.js :

```
.controller("detail", ["$scope", "$http", "$stateParams", function($scope, $http, $stateParams){

  var config = {
    headers : {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  $http.get("http://example.com/app/detay.php?id=" + $stateParams.id, config)
  .success(function(response){
    $scope.description = (response[0].description);
    $scope.name = (response[0].name);
  })
}])
```

sample json data that i use :

```
[{"id":"803","name":"At Kafas\u0131","description":"<p>Kahve fal\u0131nda at kafasm\u0131 g\u00f6rmek, iyi ve mutlu bir haber alaca\u011f\u0131n\u0131za, geli\u015fmelerin hayat\u0131n\u0131za olumlu etkilerde bulunaca\u011f\u0131n\u0131n bir i\u015faretidir.Zenginli\u011fi ve bereketin sembol\u00fc olan at kafas\u0131, i\u015f ve okul hayat\u0131n\u0131zda \u00e7ok ba\u015far\u0131l\u0131 olaca\u011f\u0131n\u0131za, uzun zamand\u0131r ilgi g\u00f6sterdi\u011finiz bir ki\u015finin duygular\u0131n\u0131za kar\u015f\u0131l\u0131k verece\u011finin bir habercisidir.<\/p>\n<p>Kahve fal\u0131nda at kafas\u0131 g\u00f6rmek, i\u015f hayat\u0131n\u0131zda yorucu ge\u00e7en g\u00fcnlerin sonunda nihayet uzun bir s\u00fcredir ev sahibi olma iste\u011finiz ger\u00e7ekle\u015fecek ve \u00e7ok g\u00fczel bir eve sahip olacakt\u0131r. Maddi ve manevi olarak y\u00fckseli\u015fler sizi bekliyor.\u0130\u015f yerinizdeki ya\u015fad\u0131\u011f\u0131n\u0131z haks\u0131zl\u0131klar ve \u00e7al\u0131\u015fmalar\u0131n\u0131z\u0131n kar\u015f\u0131l\u0131\u011f\u0131 olan paray\u0131 alamaman\u0131z her ne kadar moralinizi bozsada hakk\u0131n\u0131z\u0131 yasal yollarla araman\u0131z gerekti\u011fini sak\u0131n unutmay\u0131n. A\u015fk hayat\u0131n\u0131zda karma\u015f\u0131k duygular ya\u015fayacaks\u0131n\u0131z ve se\u00e7im yapmakta olduk\u00e7a zorlanacaks\u0131n\u0131z, bu gibi d\u00f6nemlerde kalbinizin sesini dinlemeyi ihmal etmeyin.<\/p>\n<p>.Kahve fal\u0131nda at kafas\u0131 g\u00f6rmek ne anlama gelir sorusunun bir di\u011fer cevab\u0131, arkada\u015f \u00e7evrenizde olduk\u00e7 samimi oldu\u011funuz ki\u015filerin nihayet ger\u00e7ek y\u00fcz\u00fcn\u00fc g\u00f6receksiniz ve istemedi\u011finiz olaylar ile kar\u015f\u0131 kar\u015f\u0131ya kalarak olduk\u00e7a \u00fcz\u00fcleceksiniz. \u0130nsanlar\u0131, kendiniz gibi iyi g\u00f6rmeyi art\u0131k b\u0131rak\u0131n ve hayat\u0131n ger\u00e7eklerini fark etmenin zaman\u0131 geldi.<\/p>\n"}]
```

and here is my html :

```
<div ng-controller="detail">

      <div class="overview" ng-bind-html="description">
        <p>
          <h2><b>Kahve Falında {{name}} Görmek</b></h2>
          <br>
          {{description}}
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I didn't use ng-repeat because I'm not going to print list of items. Do I have to use ng-repeat in all circumstances? @Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out FINALLY.

So there is no problem in my code which pulls name and description.

The problem is the `ng-bind-html="description"` inside `div`. I was using it to extract description data with tags to my html. But it created problem for `{{name}}`. So I moved `ng-bind-html="description"` to `<p>` tag which contains `{{description}}` and everything worked fine.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I tried mark it but it says that "You can accept your own answer in 2 days", thats because i'm new in this platform i think

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shammelburg/hsyhmgc9/7/) with the data from the service.

When making an HTTP request using `$http` I would recommend using a promise.

```
$http.get("http://falimda.com/app/detay.php?id=" + $stateParams.id, config)
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.description = response.data[0].description;
      $scope.name = response.data[0].name;
});
```

JSFiddle does not allow this but please try this in your IDE/Code editor.

Comment: I tried but it but it didn't work, the JsFiddle works fine and makes sense but I don't know why when I change my code in that way it doesn't work. @shammelburg

Comment: @Burak Güneli, your service calls fine in the browser, I have tried to access it through my angular app using `$http.get` and there seems to be a CORS issue, you need to allow access to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see any wrong with your code but try this fiddle.

```
obj = response[0]
name = obj.name
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zk8z7mb1/1/

Comment: Did you see the fiddle? I think that's just the same. 
Just try the rename your variable from name to name2, maybe there's a conflict.

Comment: yeah I saw the fiddle but unfortunetly it didn't work in my code

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong, but do you sure you put in the right ng-app?

I think you should try to test one thing, you create 1 variable like $scope.test = "test" and show it to the UI {{test}}.

If it's not appear, I think you should review your code whether you're using right your app.

Thanks,
Good luck.